# SharePoint Online: Get Document Library Children Count Using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint, csom, sharepoint-clientobject

My requirement is to get the children item count of Document Library using CSOM. The count should only be the immediate children count, and should not include the sub-children count. I am trying to use below code to achieve this:

```
var newObjClientContext = this.GetSharePointClientContext(accessToken, fullUri);
WebCollection collWeb = newObjClientContext.Web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser(new SubwebQuery());
var documentLibrary = newObjClientContext.Web.Lists.GetById(docID);

ListItemCollection ltitems = null;

string vquery = @"<View >
                <Query>
                    <Where> 
                        <Or> 
                            <Eq>
                                <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /> 
                                <Value Type='Lookup'>1</Value>
                            </Eq> 
                            <Eq>
                                <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /> 
                                <Value Type='Lookup'>0</Value>
                            </Eq> 
                            </Or> 
                        </Where>
                        <OrderBy><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' Ascending='TRUE'></FieldRef></OrderBy>                                        
                    </Query>
                    <RowLimit>" + recCount + @"</RowLimit>
                    </View>";

CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();

camlQuery.ViewXml = vquery;
ltitems = documentLibrary.GetItems(camlQuery);
newObjClientContext.Load(documentLibrary);
newObjClientContext.Load(ltitems, lists => lists.IncludeWithDefaultProperties(l => l.ParentList));

newObjClientContext.ExecuteQuery();

int totalcount = documentLibrary.ItemCount; //It includes count of all the items present at all levels.
```

Can anyone suggest how can I get children count in above step?

Comment: do you mean item count of items selected by query?

Comment: No, the items selected by above query will be limited by the specified "RowLimit". I want to get the total children count of that document library.

Comment: Well, not possible. What are you trying to achieve? Control with pagination?

Comment: Yes, and for the same reason I need total count so that number of pages can be displayed accordingly in UI.

Comment: so you have two options, perform lightweight query with no rowlinit or use unlimited pager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have interpreted your requirement correctly you want the root level child item count of the document library? This is easily achieved using the `ItemCount` property of document libraries `RootFolder`.

```
var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
cc.Load(list.RootFolder, l => l.ItemCount);
cc.ExecuteQuery();

var rootChildItemCount = list.RootFolder.ItemCount;
```

Or do you require the child item count of every folder in your document library? This can be achieved with a `CamlQuery`. Let me know if your require a solution for this.